# Download option for pdf generated by Jasper reports in browsers not working

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

Im trying to generate a pdf using jasper reports. Its generating fine and its storing in the specified path directly. But what I needed is, it has to show the open or save option before downloading directly. Im using struts 1.x

Here is my code which I hve written in the method

```
String reportsPath = "D:/JasperReports/";
String reportName = "StatisticsReport";
Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
parameters.put("statisticsData", map);

// Load JRXML

 JasperDesign mainReportDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(reportsPath + reportName + ".jrxml");
// Compile to generate .Jasper file
   JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(mainReportDesign, reportsPath + reportName + ".jasper");

   System.out.println(reportsPath + reportName);
                 // Generate Jasper print
   JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportsPath + reportName + ".jasper", parameters,
                             new JREmptyDataSource());

   String pdfFileName = "D:/JasperReports/StatisticsrReport.pdf";
                 // Export PDF file
   response.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=StatisticsrReport1.pdf");
                 JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint,pdfFileName);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browser will prompt to save or open file when response content type is `application/x-download`. For example:

```
//String pdfFileName = "D:/JasperReports/StatisticsrReport.pdf";
response.setContentType("application/x-download");
response.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=StatisticsrReport1.pdf");
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint,out);//export PDF directly
//return null ActionForward, no extra data is appended to output stream
```

Comment: Let me check and get back to you.